# SQL Query for avoiding any repetition for a specific column terms

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking to design a query in which I need DISTINCT terms in a column without repetition. I am using the SQL Server 2008 R2 edition.

Here is my sample table:

```
id  bank_code   bank_name   interest_rate
----------------------------------------------------------
1   123         abc         3.5
2   456         xyz         3.7
3   123         abc         3.4
4   789         pqr         3.3
5   123         abc         3.6
6   456         xyz         3.1
```

What I want is, to sort the table descending on the 'interest_rates' column but without any repetition of the terms in 'bank_code'.

Here is what I want:

```
id  bank_code   bank_name   interest_rate
----------------------------------------------------------
2   456         xyz         3.7 
5   123         abc         3.6
4   789         pqr         3.3
```

I have been trying the DISTINCT operator but it selects the unique combination of all the columns and not the single column for repetition.
Here is what I am doing, which clearly would not do get me what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [ID], [BANK_CODE]
      ,[BANK_NAME]
      ,[INTEREST_RATE]
  FROM [SAMPLE]
  ORDER BY [INTEREST_RATE] DESC
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to decide on what basis you select the interest rate, from your results it looks like the maximum interest rate for a given bank_code / bank_name. But the ID does not appear to follow this, so can you explain the logic for ID selection?

Comment: The ID corresponds to the record which is selected/sorted. I don't want to sort (or perform any other operation) on/with the ID column.

Comment: your result row for abc does not follow that rule. abc for 3.6 has an id of 5.

Comment: @Andrew is right - the second row in your result should show ID = 5, not ID = 1. If you don't care about the ID then maybe you shouldn't bother including it in the result?

Comment: Oops,my bad! Edited now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT id,bank_code,bank_name,interest_rate,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bank_code ORDER BY interest_rate DESC)
    FROM dbo.[SAMPLE]
)
SELECT id,bank_code,bank_name,interest_rate
FROM x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY interest_rate DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using analytical functions:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bank_code ORDER BY interes_rate DESC) Corr
    FROM [Sample]
)
SELECT id, bank_code, banck_name, interest_rate
FROM CTE 
WHERE Corr = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the `[]` syntax, but you probably need something like this:

```
SELECT min([ID]), [BANK_CODE], [BANK_NAME], max([INTEREST_RATE])
FROM [SAMPLE]
GROUP BY [BANK_CODE], [BANK_NAME]
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: This is not going to produce the right result, the ID and the interest rate will not correspond.

Comment: I don't know if grouping is right here... for one it mixes up two of the columns potentially, since the highest interest rate isn't necessarily matched with the lowest ID. Plus what if there are two cases where the interest rate is the same? You'll return two rows. Also please don't use `ORDER BY <ordinal>`... this is very fragile (see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). If you give your column an alias (as you should) then you can reference the alias name instead of where the column is in the result set right now.

Comment: it's not mine, you can write whatever aliases you need and use them in ORDER BY - and `max()` is a group function, it will return 1 row no matter how many rows have the same maximum value

Comment: @deathApril - It still can choose the wrong Id for the max interest_rate

Comment: @Andrew well, that criterium was not in the original question - but you are right, they won't correspond.. other answers are already here, no need for me to update mine ;)

Comment: @Lamak yes it can. selecting arbitrary ID corresponding to arbitrary INTEREST_RATE has no meaning in the first place => i saw no reason to be picky about it..

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. It is simple, but will duplicate if you have interest rates that are the same.

```
select ID, #sample.Bank_code, bank_name, #sample.interest_Rate
from #sample
join  
(
   SELECT [BANK_CODE], MAX(interest_rate) as interest_Rate
   FROM #sample
   GROUP BY bank_code
) as groupingtable
    on groupingtable.bank_code = #sample.bank_code 
        and groupingtable.interest_Rate = #sample.interest_rate
```